# COMO AGRUPO LOS ID Y QUE ME MUESTRE LOS DEMAS REGISTROS? EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Ayúdenme.
tengo la siguientes tablas como ejemplo, pero en realidad son muchos campos aquí solo coloque 3 id(20,25,35).
aclarado esto, vamos al ejemplo:
tengo tabla1, que tiene id y nombre de tabla_2
como se muestra continuación :

[image: tabla1]

Como hago para agrupar todos los campos excepto id_tabla2 y nombre.
el resultado que necesitaría seria:
que por cada id de la tabla 1 me muestre todos los id y nombre de la tabla 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui mi consulta:

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.id, t2.nombre
FROM tabla_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN t2 AS t2 ON t2.id_tabla2 = t1.id
```

Comment: En tu consulta la penúltima columna del SELECT es `t2.id`, pero en los datos de ejemplo el encabezado dice `Id_tabla2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es un JSON, lo puedes generar con las funciones propias de MySQL 8:

```
SELECT json_object( 
         'tablas', json_arrayagg( 
                      json_object( 
                        'id'         , t1.id
                      , 'descripcion', t1.descripcion
                      , 'personas'   , ( SELECT json_arrayagg( 
                                                  json_object( 'id'    , t2.id2 
                                                             , 'nombre', t2.nombre
                                                             )
                                                )
                                           FROM tabla_2 t2
                                           WHERE t2.id1 = t1.id
                                       ) 
                      ) 
                   ) 
      )  json
  FROM tabla_1 t1
```

Deberá resultar en un JSON mas manejable:

```
{ "tablas": [ { "id": 20
              , "descripcion": "soleado"
              , "personas": [ { "id": 1
                              , "nombre": "Ana"
                              }
                            , { "id": 2
                              , "nombre": "Sofia"
                              }
                            , { "id": 3
                              , "nombre": "Daniela"
                              }
                            , { "id": 4
                              , "nombre": "Salome"
                              }
                            ]
              }
            , { "id": 25
              , "descripcion": "rojo"
              , "personas": [ { "id": 5
                              , "nombre": "Sara"
                              }
                            , { "id": 6
                              , "nombre": "Maria"
                              }
                            , { "id": 10
                              , "nombre": "Juan"
                              }
                            ]
              }
            , { "id": 35
              , "descripcion": "arena"
              , "personas": [ { "id": 11
                              , "nombre": "Roberto"
                              }
                            , { "id": 12
                              , "nombre": "Luis"
                              }
                            , { "id": 15
                              , "nombre": "Santiago"
                              }
                            , { "id": 20
                              , "nombre": "Omar"
                              }
                            ]
              }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que por cómo se ve en tu respuesta esperada, requieres que solo se muestre "la cabecera" de la tabla_a, en ese caso un ejemplo que te puedo poner es el siguiente:

Esta es una réplica de tu ejemplo (realizada en MSSQL, los demás scripts son los que funcionan en MySQL versión 8.0 en adelante):

```sql
select *
into #a
from(
  values(20,'soleado'),(21,'nublado')
) as x(id,[desc]);

select *
into #b
from(
  values(1,'ana',20),(2,'pablo',20),
  (3,'ruperta',21),(4,'camila',21)
) as y(id,nombre,id_a)
```

Para ello primero realizo un `row_number` para identificar la cabecera de la tabla_a y así solo mostrar esa fila y omitir el resto (con omitir no me refiero a los datos, sino a la visualización de los mismos), esto así tal cual no serviría así que lo meto en un CTE:

```sql
;with resumen as(
  select cast(a.id as varchar) idA, a.[desc] descA, 
  b.id idB, b.nombre nomB, b.id_a id_aB, 
  row_number() over(partition by a.id order by a.id) nroFila
from #a as a
join #b as b on a.id = b.id_a
)
```

Por último hacemos uso del CTE creado y usamos `case...when` para mostrar solo las cabeceras, es decir, aquellas filas que tengan 1 en el campo nroFila:

```sql
select case when nroFila = 1 then idA else '' end id,
  case when nroFila = 1 then descA else '' end [desc], 
  idB, nomB
from resumen
```

La salida final quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```sql
+--------------+-----+---------+
| id | desc    | idB | nomB    |
+--------------+-----+---------+
| 20 | soleado | 1   | ana     |
|    |         | 2   | pablo   |
| 21 | nublado | 3   | ruperta |
|    |         | 4   | camila  |
+--------------+-----+---------+
```

Espero puedas aplicarlo cómo convengas, saludos!

Comment: Hola buen dia, No son las cabeceras que quiero mostrar son los id que contengan {los id de tabla 2 y descripcion de tabla 2} para poder mandarlo en un json dentro de lumen

Comment: El json que deberia mostrar con esa consulta seria:
Tablas { "id":"20"
{ "id_tabla2": "1 ",
      "nombre": "ana",
      "id_tabla2": "2",
      "nombre": "sofia",
    "id_tabla2": "3",
      "nombre": "daniela",
      "id_tabla2": "4",
      "nombre": "salome",
      }
},
    Tablas  { "id":"25",
      "id_tabla2": "5 ",
      "nombre": "sara",
      "id_tabla2": "6",
      "nombre": "maria",
      "id_tabla2": "10",
      "nombre": "juan"
    }, 
Tablas { "id":"35"
         "id_tabla2": "11 "
nombre": "ana".....